# Code128 barcode language independent

Tags: barcode

I'm using this [code128 barcode font](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/Code128.aspx). It works fine, but when I have an underscore (_) my usb barcode reader automatically transforms it in a minus (-). I tryed to switch the keyboard language and I get a slash (/). So, I suppose there's a problem with the language. I'd like to have a barcode that is language independent. Is this possible? How?

The code I used to generate the barcode representation is like the one stated [here](http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm).

Comment: What your saying doesn't make sense. The underscore is an underscore in code 128 and shouldn't get confused with anything else. My suggestion is to manually decode the barcode and see what is actually being encoded. To manually decode the barcode, you can blow the barcode up real big on a piece of paper and use a ruler and pencil or scan it into photoshop (or similar) and count pixels. Determine which start code you are using and if the bar pattern or the underscore is a 1 1 1 2 2 4 [link](http://www.adams1.com/128table.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. I found the solution, read below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved. The problem was the setting of my barcode scanner (a Datalogic HeronG). I set the USB interface to `USB-KBD - ALT-mode`. In the `USB-KBD` mode, the scanner simulates the national keyboard.